# What mental consequences can have remembering an event from two different points of view?

Tags: magic

(How the ability work)

- The process is instantaneous. The clone appears somewhere you want as long as you can have skin-to-skin contact. (Touching your nails or hair is also a valid contact)
- You are only able to replicate your person, your body, not what you wear or anything that is not part of your person. (for example if your hair is wet, when you create the clone her/his hair won't be.)
- The state of the body also replicates perfectly, each marathon, each broken nail, the clone will also have. Either of the two entities (the clone or the original) receives some damage after the cloning will not affect the other.
- The clone will have all the memories you have until the exact moment in which it has just materialized. (Imagine thinking that you want to create a clone, you blink and in front of you you see yourself, dressed, you are not dressed, you are the clone) From then on, the two entities are self-conscious beings completely autonomous but they are still The same person with the same goals.
- You and the clone can get back together in a single individual, agreeing to do so and in which body you stay. Bouth memories and experiences will be remembered by the individual that remains as theirs. (Imagine that you walk on a path of two different colors and each one walks in one color watching how the other walks on the other. You will remember to walk on the red path while watching the clone walk on the white path while remembering to walk on the white path watching as the clone walks on the red path)
- If either dies, regardless of whether it is the clone or not, their body will vanish as well as their memories.
- If there there are two of you none of you can create a clone. If one of you dies, the other won't be able to create a clone.

**Edit:** Clone in the context of this skill is interchangeable with twin.

I would like to know if it would affect in any way in the short or long term having memories of multiple events during the same time frame.

If it would have any consequence to realize that you are the clone if for any practical purpose (as soon as you put on some clothes) you are exactly the same person.

And I would also like to know if such a skill would have some other use that is not obvious at first glance. Those that have occurred to me for noware 1-Unlimited stamina (you can create a clone, one of the two starts digging, for example and the other sits down to read. When the digger gets tired he goes to the one who is reading, they keep together, the memories of having worked and having read in the body that is rested and this creates a completely rested clone again.) 2-The perfect ish escapist (You are impossible to lock between bars, if you can pass your finger trough, you can escape. You create a clone out, while still touching your fingers you fuse in the body outside.)

**Edit:** Changed the title question to better suit what I am looking for.

Comment: But you just said the clone is an *exact duplicate* of yourself at the moment you were cloned. That means if *you* are exhausted (and your muscles are fatigued from digging, with depleted substrates, depleted oxygen), then your clone is also fatigued. Your clone can't dig for you if he is also fatigued.  It sounds like the clone is actually "almost a clone" with none of the bad stuff. Is that right?

Comment: @VogonPoet Unless you don't work. the clone does!

Comment: When fusing back together you can choose what body will remain, the tired digger or the well rested reader. By choosing the reader the body will be rested and in creating a clone this one will be as well. In the other hand you may want to keep the body of the digger if you are not going to work any more, this way you can build musle over time. Does that make sense?

Comment: But either way you keep both memories? So if the one relaxing was making office calls, and the one digging was working a construction job, you fuse and have all the memories of each? You can literally do two professions ate the same time.

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: Does anyone else do this? What about a spouse or friend? How do they keep track of you - that would be traumatizing. "Which one am I on a date with now?"

Comment: @VogonPoet "Darling, you have a clone to do your paranoid fretting for you. Why not just enjoy the evening?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, I do not think there is no distinction between clone and original. It is more like splitting a person into two twins. Psychologically, I also feel that having a clone is same as having a twin.

More uses:

- Generally more time in the day. The twins perfect team at work, or one can work while other spends time with family. You can work a clone to near-death too.
- Extreme sports: losing ability to clone is a lot better than losing one's life.
- Escapes and breaking and entering will be easier, but people will respond with using solid doors and walls instead of grills and fences. And keeping air ducts too small for a clone.
- Military: soldier generates a clone, they toss a coin to see who goes to fight, and who stays at camp and trains. If fighting twin is killed, the survivor retires. Otherwise, they merge at the end of the day. If fighting twin deserts, the camp twin is punished. You can have merged soldier suffer from memories of severe wounds, fighters considering escape, camp twin trying to hunt down the fighter who deserted or got captured, etc.

Issues:

- Criminal responsibility, aka "my clone did it" defense. Can police tell if somebody is a clone or has a clone running around? Can you prove cloning after the merger? Can a clone run off and live independently until old age?
- Workplace expectations. Now that you can work double the hours, many companies will expect you to do just that. In creative/brainy jobs, having same worker with double hours is a lot more valuable than having two workers.

**[addition] Having two sets of memories** does have implications.

Brain capacity is limited, so I suspect the merged individual will forget merged memories twice as fast as single-person memories.

Having two memories of same event (own and twin's) sounds similar to seeing oneself in a camera. That might could lead to dissociation, e.g. if twin's memories are more intense:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociation_(psychology)

Finally, memories are stored as state of neurons in the brains (chemicals and connections between them). And OP says that twins choose which body to inherit, and neurons are part of the body. So merging memories from two brains into one is far from straightforward. Maybe the longer the twins stay separate, the harder it is to merge, and the higher is the risk of madness of some sort.

Comment: Remember this is magic. I think its a pure psychosocial exercise. All physics and physiology is out the window.